# How to space columns evenly in a table with multicolumns?

Tags: tables, spacing, multicolumn, booktabs

A hopefully very simple question. Why does the multicolumn in my example below screw up the spacing between the columns below? Obviously I would want columns A, B, and C to be spaced evenly (as they are if I comment the multicolumn-row). How to achieve this?

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}

\newcommand{\crule}[1]{\multispan{#1}{\hspace*{\tabcolsep}\hrulefill\hspace*{\tabcolsep}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!t]
    \caption{bla.} 
    \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{}l@{\extracolsep\fill}c@{\extracolsep\fill}c@{\extracolsep\fill}c@{}}
    \toprule
        & \multicolumn{3}{c}{sample number}\\
        & \crule{3}\\ % definition should still include some neg. vspace after that
        & 1 & 2 & 3\\
    \midrule
    some longer text here  & A    & B   & C\\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular*}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

results in

[image: the resulting table]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Column widths are assigned *before* the "extra" skips are stretched, and if a spanning cell is wider than the columns it spans, all space goes into the last spanned column.

So you either need to hide the width of the span as below, or increase the natural width eg change `\fill` to `1cm plus 1fill` so that the spanning cell doesn't force the columns wider.

Not you don't need to repeat `\extracolsep` it applies to all further columns until reset.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}

\newcommand{\crule}[1]{\multispan{#1}{\hspace*{\tabcolsep}\hrulefill\hspace*{\tabcolsep}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[tp]%[!t]
    \caption{bla.} 
    \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{}l@{\extracolsep\fill}c@{\extracolsep\fill}c@{\extracolsep\fill}c@{}}
    \toprule
        & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\makebox[0pt]{sample number}}\\
        & \crule{3}\\ % definition should still include some neg. vspace after that
        & 1 & 2 & 3\\
    \midrule
    some longer text here  & A    & B   & C\\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular*}
    \label{tab:Mg2Si_Variation_SD}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

If `tabular*` is not a must, may be is simpler use `tabularx`  of the same package of David Carlisle.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{
l
>{\centering}X
>{\centering}X
>{\centering\arraybackslash}X
}
\toprule
 & \multicolumn{3}{c}{sample number}\\
\cmidrule{2-4}
 & 1 & 2 & 3\\
\midrule
some longer text here  & A    & B   & C   \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image: MWE]

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
  \usepackage{array}
  \usepackage{booktabs}
  \newlength\ColSpacing
% \setlength{\ColSpacing}{7em}

\begin{document}
  \begin{table}[!h]
  \caption{bla.}
  \centering
  \setlength{\ColSpacing}{7em}
  \begin{tabular}{cccc}
    & \hspace{\ColSpacing} & \hspace{\ColSpacing} & \hspace{\ColSpacing} \\
    \toprule
    & \multicolumn{3}{c}{sample number}\\
    \cmidrule{2-4}
    & 1 & 2 & 3\\ \midrule 
    some longer text here & A & B & C\\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
  \flushleft
  \end{table}

  \vspace{10ex}
  \begin{tabular}{c*{3}{wc{7em}}}
    \toprule
    & \multicolumn{3}{c}{sample number}\\
    \cmidrule{2-4}
    & 1 & 2 & 3\\ \midrule 
    some longer text here & A & B & C\\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
  \flushleft

\end{document}
```

Comment: Your solution adds an empty line above the `\toprule` of the table, thus increasing the vertical space between caption and `\toprule`. In order to get fixed width centered columns, you could use `\begin{tabular}{c*{3}{wc{7em}}}` instead. (Needs the `array` package.)

Comment: Good suggestion Leandris. Looks like the more correct way of doing it.