# Evenly Space longtable columns with multicolumn

Tags: longtable, multicolumn

I'm having a spacing issue in `longtable`, where the use of `multicolumn` elongates the last column. Example posted below.

The solution suggested to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/245096) does not appear to work for me (`\fill` threw up an error), but I suspect the issue is similar.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{longtable}

\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}b{#1}}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{longtable}{@{\extracolsep{6pt}}*{5}{L{1.75cm}}}
\toprule\multicolumn{3}{l}{\textbf{Survey Code}} & \multicolumn{2}{r}{\textbf{Month/Year (Sample Size)}} \\ \midrule 
\endfirsthead

\multicolumn{5}{c}%
{{\bfseries \tablename\ \thetable{} -- continued from previous page}} \\
\toprule\multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{Survey Code}} & \multicolumn{4}{r}{\textbf{Month/Year (Sample Size)}} \\ \midrule 
\endhead

\midrule\multicolumn{5}{l}{{Continued on next page}} \\\bottomrule
\endfoot

\bottomrule
\endlastfoot

\multicolumn{3}{l}{Polling Organization} & \multicolumn{2}{r}{(Mo./Yr.) ($N=XXXX$)} \\[1em]
\multicolumn{5}{p{\textwidth}}{\footnotesize \emph{Survey question text goes here.}} \\[1em]
\\[.25em]

\multicolumn{1}{L{2cm}}{Response 1} & \multicolumn{1}{L{2cm}}{Response 2} & \multicolumn{1}{L{2cm}}{Response 3} & \multicolumn{1}{L{2cm}}{Response 4} & \multicolumn{1}{L{2cm}}{Response 5}\\\cmidrule{1-1}\cmidrule{2-2}\cmidrule{3-3}\cmidrule{4-4}\cmidrule{5-5}
\nopagebreak
\multicolumn{1}{p{2cm}}{20\%} & \multicolumn{1}{p{2cm}}{56\%} & \multicolumn{1}{p{2cm}}{6\%} & \multicolumn{1}{p{2cm}}{8\%} & \multicolumn{1}{p{2cm}}{10\%} \\[2em]
\end{longtable}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Are your table is multi page long? If not, than is better to use ordinary `tabular` environment.  Can you add some more rows,  that we can see size of numbers in columns.

Comment: It's multi-page, but I reduced the example to a single "entry," in order to make it more manageable.

Comment: You could use \multicolumn{1}{L{0.2\textwidth-2\tabcolsep}}{Response 1}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I correctly understood your question, than you like to have the following table (unfortunately it is not clear, what is in the not showing rows, ore there only numbers?):

[image]

(red lines indicate text borders)

- table has equal width of columns determined with `p{\dimexpr0.2\textwidth-2\tabcolsep}`
- for `\multicolumn`s are defined shortnes with use of the `xparse` package

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs, longtable, makecell}

\usepackage{xparse}
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand\mcl{O{1}m}
    {\multicolumn{#1}{l}{#2}}
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand\mcr{O{1}m}
    {\multicolumn{#1}{r}{#2}}
\newcommand\mcp[1]{\multicolumn{1}{p{0.16\linewidth}}{#1}}
%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\begingroup
\begin{longtable}{ *{5}{p{\dimexpr0.2\textwidth-2\tabcolsep}} 
                 } 
    \caption{Caption on the first page of the table}
    \label{tab:longtable}                               \\
    \toprule
\mcl[2]{\textbf{Survey Code}}
            & \mcr[3]{\textbf{Month/Year (Sample Size)}} \\
    \midrule
\endfirsthead
    \caption[]{Caption on the first page of the table}  \\
    \toprule
\mcl[2]{\textbf{Survey Code}}
            & \mcr[3]{\textbf{Month/Year (Sample Size)}} \\
    \midrule
\endhead
    \midrule[\heavyrulewidth]
\mcr[5]{r}{\small\textit{Continued on next page}}       \\
\endfoot
    \bottomrule
\endlastfoot
%%%% table body
\mcl[2]{Polling Organization}
            & \mcr[3]{(Mo./Yr.) ($N=XXXX$)}             \\
    \midrule
    \addlinespace
\multicolumn{5}{>{\small}p{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\tabcolsep}}{\emph{Survey question text goes here.}

        \medskip
        \lipsum[11]}                                    \\ % dummy text
    \addlinespace
{Response 1}
        & {Response 2}
                    & {Response 3}
                            & {Response 4}
                                    & {Response 5}      \\
    \cmidrule(r){1-1}\cmidrule(r){2-2}
    \cmidrule(r){3-3}\cmidrule(r){4-4}\cmidrule{5-5}
20\,\%  & 56\,\%    & 6\,\% & 8\,\% & 10\,\%            \\
   \end{longtable}
\endgroup
\end{document}
    \end{longtable}
\endgroup
\end{document}
```